# Why is this loop within a loop not running to completion?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I need the loop to iterate through A1,A2..A8..B8...H8 but it stops at C3 for some reason. For the life of me I cannot figure out why this loop within a loop is not running.

P.S letters is just an arraylist of the alphabet {A,B,C...Z} and getValue() just returns a value depending on how much a letter is worth.

```
int bestMove = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
        System.out.println(letters.get(i) + "" + (x+1));

        int distanceRow = currentRow - i;
        int distanceCol = currentCol - x;
        distanceRow = Math.abs(distanceRow);
        distanceCol = Math.abs(distanceCol);

        if(currentRow == i && currentCol == x){
            System.out.println("if");
        } else if (distanceRow - distanceCol == 0) {
            bestMove = getValue(getPiece(i, x));
            System.out.print("else if");
            System.out.println(letters.get(i) + "" + (x+1));
        } else {
            System.out.print(letters.get(i) + "" + (x+1));
            System.out.println("else");
        }
    }
```

Edit: I tested it as was suggested and it seems theres an error with this method although I dont know what since it just returns a value

```
 public int getValue(String piece) {

        if (piece.equals(w1)) {
            return 1;
        } else if (piece.equals(w2)) {
            return 3;
        } else if (piece.equals(w3)) {
            return 3;
        } else if (piece.equals(w4)) {
            return 5;
        } else if (piece.equals(w5)) {
            return 9;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: as far as i can tell, there is nothing wrong with the iteration itself, the problem should be in one of your functions (getPiece, getValue), maybe they run into some kind of endless loop.. ? You can also remove these functions to check, what causes the reak problem.

Comment: Well, did you step through each line of code in the debugger?

Comment: There is probably some error in one of your functions. Good practice is to always trying calling your function inside of some simple program, so you can see its behavior and catch the bugs in function, rather than having to wonder if the code implementing the function is at fault.

Comment: Is there any error messages? Stacktrace? It would help if you post your getValue function also your letters arraylist so we can reproduce the problem and help you.

Comment: I agree with @OldProgrammer, use a debugger and step through the code.  You can inspect the variables and should be able to figure out what's happening.   Are there any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: The nested loop doesn't make sense anyway. There's a number of pairs (x,i) where `distanceRow - distanceCol == 0` and `bestMove = getValue(getPiece(i, x))`will remain to be set by the last of these pairs. This can be calculated without a loop.

Comment: When you say it "stops" at C3 do you mean that it hangs, it crashes, it terminates, it throws an exception... ? Also, since it gets to C3 why do you say that the inner loop "is not running" ?

Comment: It doesn't show any errors it just stops at C3, also ignore the fact that the bestMove = getValue() gives the value of the last number, I just haven't finished that part completely.

Comment: Can you please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? We need it to reproduce your  problem.

Comment: I just tried to recreate it and the problem went so i think its something to do with another part of my code. Thanks for that idea, helped me sort of pin point where my error is.